# Determining input datatype Oracle/PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am writing a PLSQL **'INSTEAD OF INSERT'** Trigger whereby the ID field (GID) can be inserted as either a string or a number. If the GID value is a string I would like to attempt to convert that into the correct GID (number) otherwise if a number is input the script will continue.

The part I am struggling with here is determining the datatype of ':New.CHART_GID' - is this possible in PLSQL? I can't check for chars in the string as the string may only contain numbers in some instances.

Thanks.

Comment: Normally you would write a function that attempts to convert the value to a number and suppresses conversion errors. Perhaps I am missing something though as I didn't follow what you meant by _"I can't check for chars in the string as the string may only contain numbers in some instances."_

Comment: @WilliamRobertson If a string is input I want to use that string to query for the gid - I want to input a value which isn't the gid into the gid field and use that to find the gid. Does this make sense?

Comment: `:new.chart_gid` will be whatever data type was declared for the `chart_gid` column in the view.  Presumably, that will always be a `varchar2` (you can always convert a number to a string, you can't always convert a string to a number).  You won't be able to determine whether the actual `INSERT` statement into the view had a number that was implicitly cast to a string before your trigger fired or whether the `INSERT` statement had a string.

Comment: @lamb - no, not really.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TRANSLATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm) to check if there is something other as numbers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
INSTEAD OF INSERT
ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 vGID INTEGER;
  ...... other things
BEGIN
   IF :New.CHART_GID is not null AND TRANSLATE(:New.CHART_GID,'0123456789',' ') is null THEN
        vGID := TO_NUMBER(:New.CHART_GID);
        .... do what you want with number
   ELSE
       ... do what you want with not number
   END IF;
  .... other things
END;
```

CHART_GID have to be varchar2 in the view

Answer (score 0):

I realise what I was trying to achieve was actually not possible. The solution for me was actually to join the Chart_no into the view and insert into either that field of the GID. If I input a Chart_no the GID field would be automatically populated and the same for if I input a GID.